# Executing some code when a push notification is recived on onMessage()

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, push-notification, android-service

This is my code, and I have to execute some http request in an AsyncTask when a push notification is received.
As I understood if I need to do something when a push notification arrives, I have to do it within the OnMessage() method.
However the app crashes when it receives the notification and does not do what I need it to do:
Code:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
    //sends info to the server

    new PostAsyncTask().execute();

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

Thank you very much!
(In case you need the whole class just say it. However I can tell you that the PostAsyncTask executes some httpRequest code.)

Logcat:

http://pastebin.com/LggC0uFq

AsyncTask:
(It just calls a function that executes some http request)

```
class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
     protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        ReNewCoordinates();
         postData(lat, lon);
            return true;

     }

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         // show progress dialog
     }


         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
             // hide  progress dialog
         }
     }
```

Comment: Can you show us your logcat?

Comment: Instead of using AsyncTask use Thread, I am using same where I am downloading image in Thread when Push notification received .

Comment: I dont think thats the problem. Even when I dont use asyncTask and just call some methods that execute the request It crushes.

Comment: I copied the logcat but it didnt work so well as you can see. can someone edit it for me? thanks.

Comment: can you post your PostAsyncTask

Comment: yes. Im adding it to the question

Comment: make sure you are not doing any ui operation in postdata.coz postdata is called in doInBackground method.

Comment: What is an UI operation? its like changing textviews or something? because I am only sending an httpRequest to my server.

Comment: yes means changing any views on layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you should not use AsyncTask from the onMessage method of Push Notification. You should call a service which does the task of making http connection. Also remember to use separate thread if you are using Service class as it runs on UI thread only. I hope this helps you out.